# check that string key entered correctly in the entry point of c# program? [Close]

Tags: c#

My string key is "-c".

***correct***:

```
app.exe -c config.xml
```

***wrong***:

`app.exe config.xml` // already done

`app.exe -d config.xml`   // ?

/* wrong, please input key '-c' for xml file. 
 Use: app.exe -c config.xml */

I tried to do it in ways but getting different compile errors.

**My attempts:**

```
String ckey = args[0];

String akey = "-c";
```

1)

```
bool test1 = ckey.StartsWith("-c");
```

2)

```
bool TextCompare = false ;

if (int StrCmp(ckey, akey, bool TextCompare ) != 0 ) 

{
 fin = new FileStream(args[1], FileMode.Open);
}
```

3)

```
if (ckey == akey) {...}

else if (ckey == "-i") { ... }

else Console.WriteLine("Please input correct key");
```

4)

```
if (args[0] == "-c") { ... }
```

5)

```
bool Check(akey, ckey)  
if (Check) {...}

int result = String.Compare(akey, ckey);
bool res = Convert.ToBoolean(result);
```

App.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int i;
            FileStream fin;
            if (args.Length != 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Use: app.exe -c config.xml");
                return;
            }
            try
            {
                fin = new FileStream(args[1], FileMode.Open); 
            }
            catch (IOException exc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unable to open file");
                Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
                return;
            }
            try
            {
                do
                {
                    i = fin.ReadByte();
                    if (i != -1) Console.Write((char)i);
                } while (i != -1);
            }
            catch (IOException exc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to read file");
                Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of your options are correct in the sense that will let you achieve what you want. Simplest example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args.Length != 2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Use: app.exe -c config.xml");
        return;
    }

    if (args[0] != "-c")
    {
       Console.WriteLine("wrong, please input key '-c' for xml file.");
       return; 
    }
}
```

See a live demo [here](http://goo.gl/4y1v2f).